# Pull data from 2016 but only if it is not in the previous years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am not sure if this is possible.... But can I pull data for 01-01-16 - 12/31/16 only if there was no data before then. So if they made a purchase before 01-01-16 I would not want to see any data. Bascially I am trying to find new customers for 2016. So in the example below John would NOT pull any data.

```
Name       | Item #  | Qty | Purch Date |
-----------+---------+-----+------------+
John       | 12      | 7   | 2016-01-05 | 
John       | 22      | 14  | 2011-01-06 | 
John       | 11      | 9   | 2013-02-05 |
```

In this example it would pull all 3.

```
Name       | Item #  | Qty | Purch Date |
-----------+---------+-----+------------+
John       | 12      | 7   | 2016-01-05 | 
John       | 22      | 14  | 2016-01-06 | 
John       | 11      | 9   | 2016-02-05 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL solution based on a Scalar Subquery:

```
select * from tab as t1
where purch_date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31' -- purchase in 2016
and not exists -- but no purchase by the same customer in a previous year
 ( select * from tab as t2
   where t1.name = t2.name
   and t2.purch_date < '2016-01-01' 
 )
```

Comment: Hard for me to know which one is best, but this seemed to work thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) function to get the first purchase date for each name and check if it is in the expected range of dates.

```
select name,item,qty,purch_date
from (
select t.*,
first_value(purch_date) over(partition by name order by purch_date) as first_purchase_date
from tablename t
) x
where first_purchase_date>='2016-01-01' and first_purchase_date<='2016-12-31'
--add a filter condition for purch_date if needed
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use `min()` as a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(purch_date) over (partition by name) as min_purch_date
      from t
     ) t
where min_purchase_date >= '2016-01-01' and min_purchase_date < '2017-01-01';
```

If you just want new customers in 2016, but don't need the details:

```
select t.name
from t
group by t.name
having min(purchase_date) >= '2016-01-01' and min(purchase_date) < '2017-01-01';
```